# Is WorkerService template suitable for creating application core in DDD solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm reading [this blog](https://gunnarpeipman.com/net/worker-service/) and I wonder if the worker service would be a good project type for implementing the inner part of a DDD solution (the one closest to the domain/model and the one containing all the business logic and use cases).

[image]

(Image scissored from [this blog](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).)

It seems to me that it's the case and it'd be a wiser choice than using a default web service as done previously. Sadly, as the feature is new under .NET Core 3, there's not much reliable material to google through for inspiration.

The way I figure, I could inject an instance of an inheriting class to `DbContext` into the worker without affecting the DDD architecture too. Or are there consideration that I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, Domain-Driven Design has never been an architecture style or pattern. It is the approach to design systems around business domains and to identify different levels of boundaries like the system and linguistic boundaries (bounded context) and transactional boundaries (aggregate).

The core of most applications that are built with DDD in mind is the domain model. The domain model is an old pattern, which existed long before DDD. The pattern itself and its DDD interpretation share one single important characteristic - the code that implements the domain model has no dependencies to any infrastructure. Therefore, it fits quite well to ports and adapters/hexagonal architecture.

Where exactly the domain model is hosted and what kind of application services (ports) and the edge layer (adapters) you want to have is completely orthogonal to DDD. Worker service, persistent actor, message consumer, REST or gRPC endpoint - whatever really.

Some see persistent actors as perfect candidates to represent aggregates. For me, anything that is directly coupled to any kind of infrastructure doesn't suit well to be a part of the domain model. It can very well be a good candidate to be the host and the application layer though.